# How to print Jasper report programmatically

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I have to write a code for generating the Jasper report which containing the images.
I want to send the jasper report to printer.
I tried  a Code:

```
    String Report = "C:\\Template\\"+file_name+".jrxml";//my Jasper report file
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Report,null,con);
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    /* Create an array of PrintServices */
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    int selectedService = 0;
    /* Scan found services to see if anyone suits our needs *
    for(int i = 0; i < services.length;i++)
    {
        if(services[i].getName().toUpperCase().contains("Your printer's name"))
        {
            /*If the service is named as what we are querying we select it */
                 selectedService = i;
        }
    }
    job.setPrintService(services[selectedService]);
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    MediaSizeName mediaSizeName = MediaSize.findMedia(4,4,MediaPrintableArea.INCH);
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(mediaSizeName);
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));
    JRPrintServiceExporter exporter;
    exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
    /* We set the selected service and pass it as a paramenter */
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE, services[selectedService]);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, services[selectedService].getAttributes());
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.exportReport();
```

but It gives me error as:

```
   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file : C:\Template\Alcon_Ele_Temp1.jrxml
```

Comment: You can handle image simply in the report template itself if you are using a suitable report editor.

I will prefer iReport. It is a very good editor and you can do many complex things simply if you learn this.

Please refer the link: http://www.novell.com/documentation/zenworks113/pdfdoc/ireport-ultimate-guide/ireport-ultimate-guide.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You must load a jasper print no a jasper xml. There is a page that maybe can help you http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/printservice/index.html

Answer (score 1):

1st of all you create the one controller in your print button path url and create the one method.

@RequestMapping(value = "/Print_url_link", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView methodName(Model m, @RequestParam(name = "para1") String para1) {

```
    Map<String, Object>     inputData       =   new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object>     returnData      =   new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object>     jasperParameterMap  =   new HashMap<String, Object>();

    putData.put("productionID", productionID);

    returnData = serviceName.methodName(inputData);
```

//create the serve and service Impl and Create the list of the what you want the list use it. and below list I add 0 index in list because in jasper report always list Start from the index 1.

```
    List<Record> list = (List<Record>) returnData.get("RecordList");
    list.add(0, new Record());
```

JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);

// JRDataSource interface represents the abstract representation of a JasperReports data source. All data source types must implement this interface. A data source implementation that wraps a collection of JavaBean objects.

It is common to access application data through object persistence layers like EJB,
  Hibernate, or JDO. Such applications may need to generate reports using data they
  already have available as arrays or collections of in-memory JavaBean objects.

```
    jasperParameterMap.put("ListObjectName", JRdataSource); 


    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("jrxmlviewName", jasperParameterMap);  


    return modelAndView;
```

}

Now the Jasper VIew XML Mapping

```
<bean id="jrxmlviewName"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
    p:url="classpath:com/report/jrxmlviewName.jrxml" />
```

And Now In the jrxml use the parameters to view the data in the jasper report. and sorry for the english

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the compiled file and not the jrxml file. You can compile your jrxml file in this way:

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Template\\"+file_name+".jrxml");
```

And then fill the report:

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,null,con);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jasper Report rendering library only renders .jasper file which is generated only .jrxml file is compiled.

The process is:

1. Design the Jasper Report using JasperSoft IDE. Once a report is
   designed, it will create one file with .jrxml extension; also call
   jasper report template
2. Once .jrxml file created (report template),
   next step is compile it to make it .jasper file. 
   There are two ways to compile it,

   - Compile using JasperSoft report studio
   - Problematically using Java code (using Jasper library)

   JasperCompileManager.compileReport("abc.xml");

Once it will be compiled and .jasper created it is loaded into JasperFillManager to print it.

Answer (score -1):

Problem with the if statement. you put /* sign in your if statement.

Also check that the file is there C:/Templates/filename.jrxml