# Type mismatch: cannot convert from JasperReport to JasperPrint

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, jasper-reports

I am still a newbie who has just started programming. At work I have a need to convert files from jrxml to PDF using Eclipse and Spring Boost with Jasper Report library. And this is my work.

```
package com.example.demo;
        
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        
import java.io.IOException;
        
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/report")
public class ReportController {
    
    @GetMapping("/generate")
    public String generateReport() throws JRException, IOException {
        // Load JRXML file
        String reportPath = "src/main/resources/reports/hello_world.jrxml";
        
        // Compile JRXML to JasperPrint
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);
        
        // Export JasperPrint to PDF
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "src/main/resources/reports/hello_world.pdf");
        
        return "report";
    }
}
```

And this is the line that shows the error message according to the topic I'm questioning. What do I need to fix or am I doing something wrong? Please advise if anyone understands. (The language may be a little strange because I'm not very good at English. I apologize.)

` // Compile JRXML to JasperPrint

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);`

Comment: Why you wrote or where did you get the line with the compile error of incompatible types? You probably have to do something like the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20847031/6505250

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to fix it.